# MongoDB Java API - How to combine sample aggregation with a find query?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to get a randomized sample of documents in a collection with a `find` criteria.

```
Bson sample = com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.sample(size);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("myKey", value);
```

How can I combine this `sample` aggregation with the `find` query?

Comment: What is your use case ? You can't combine aggregation with regular find operations. Use aggregation if you want sample operator.

Comment: I need to sample some documents according to a field (a boolean field) in a collection. @Veeram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation with `$match` followed by `$sample`.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

Bson match = match(eq("myKey", value));
Bson sample = sample(size);
collection.aggregate(asList(match, sample));
```

Comment: Despite that `db.coll1.count({key1: false, key2: true})` returns 2946 documents, `Bson sample = com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.sample(size);
Bson match1 = com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.match(eq("key1", true));
Bson match2 = com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.match(eq("key2", false));
Bson matchFilters = and(match1, match2); mongoDB.getCollection("coll1").aggregate(asList(sample, matchFilters))` returns only 46 documents. Any reason for this issue?

Comment: What is your sample size ? It will return documents equal to sample size and also change to `aggregate(asList(matchFilters, sample))`

Comment: Ok, after changing the order of aggregations, now it works as it is expected. Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated.